# GPS Monitoring of navy traffic and areo traffic

Tags: web-service

Some time ago I've seen two web application that monitoring in real time navy traffic and aero traffic. I haven't found it googling, can someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [one](http://www.marinetraffic.com/ais/) for ships (and [another](http://shipfinder.co/)) and [one](http://planefinder.net/) for planes